# Get user activity information from other applications

Tags: ios, objective-c, spotify, pandora

My question is that is there any way possible to get what users are listening to using other music services, such as Spotify or Pandora?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, when you know the exact service name that might be running in the system, or, you could access them anyway. Since both are not possible, so NO.

Comment: Is it not even possible for Jailbreak device?

Comment: Might possible on Jailbreak device, you need to fire command in terminal like `ps -ef |grep service name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS have everything sandboxed so apps do not mess around with data of other apps. A little while back it was absolutely impossible for 2 of your own apps to share some information with each other.
iOS 8 has changed that by [Inter-App Communication](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW2) but not to the extent where you want it. Even in iOS 8, the recepient app has to provide the functionality and should handle your incoming request to see what music they are playing.

Your better course of action would be look up if Pandora or Spotify have some API which let's users login, and share their listening history with your app.